# pdf2swf.exe Error on IIS

Tags: iis, pdf, pdf2swf

I am trying to convert PDF files to SWF using pdf2swf on windows 2008 server via `Process proc = new Process()`.

When running from Visual Studio, everything works fine. But when running from IIS, I get this on most files:

```
ERROR   Internal error: No current splash fontinfo  
ERROR   Internal error: No current splash fontinfo  
ERROR   Invalid charid 3 for font 00f896d8 (0 characters)  
ERROR   Invalid charid 615 for font 00f896d8 (0 characters)  
ERROR   Invalid charid 602 for font 00f896d8 (0 characters)
```

I believe the reason is permissions but I don't know what I have to change.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution right now. Im using windows service to convert from pdf to swf and I noticed wrong working directory. For me it was syswow64. PDF2SWF had no permissions to create temporary files. I set working directory property in ProcessStartInfo and now it works great.

Comment: What did you set the working directory to? Do you have any sample code you can share?

Comment: I believe I've figured it out and to clarify Tomq's response, you need to point the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory to wherever your PDF files are located. For example, my PDFs are uploaded to C:\FlexPaper\pdfs so I just added proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\FlexPaper\pdfs";